# Variable in bash script treated as a command - "command not found"

Tags: windows, bash

I'm using git-for-windows and want to write a bash function to update the current working branch to *master*. Here is what i have written:

```
sync() { 
        branch = $(git symbolic-ref HEAD | sed -e 's,.*/\(.*\),\1,')
        git checkout master
        git pull origin/master
        git checkout $branch
}
```

However, when i call this function, it throws an error:

> bash: branch: command not found

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the whitespace between the `=` so it reads:

`branch=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD | sed -e 's,.*/\(.*\),\1,')`